# postgres aggregration over a few tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I have the following tables:

```
targeting
-- id
-- type
-- value

performance
-- id
-- ad_name
-- installs

performance_targeting
-- id
-- performance_id
-- targeting_id
```

I would like to get for each performance, its targeting values.

In order to the achieve it, I wrote:

```
select performance_id, string_agg(value, ',' order by value) as values from 
targeting join performance_targeting
on targeting.id = performance_targeting.id
group by performance_id
```

But the results are not correct.

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/212c6/8) - as you can see, performance with id 1, is related both to targeting age 18-24 and female. I would expect the array_agg to display the following:

```
performance_id   targeting_values 
1                18-24,female
2                25-34,male
3                18-24,female
4                25-34,female
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a just small bug. You have `performance_targeting.id` instead of `performance_targeting.targeting_id`

```
select performance_id, 
   string_agg(value, ', ' ORDER BY value) as values 
from targeting 
join performance_targeting on targeting.id = performance_targeting.targeting_id
group by performance_id
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/212c6/11)

Comment: my only problem is that on a table with 30M records it takes so long to achieve this string_agg :-(

Comment: @Dejell I can imagine. And do you really need all these data, can't you employ some filter + index?

Comment: with the filter it's very slow. would the engine calculate the string_agg AFTER filtering the records?

Comment: @Dejell definitely, do you have an index supporting your predicate? use `explain` to inspect the query plan as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165249/discussion-between-dejell-and-radim-baca).